# How can I move images or widgets in flutter animation?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner in flutter, I want in start of application, a logo slowly come from top outside to the center after a couple second.

Comment: I assume you are looking for `splash screen`.

Comment: no I don't want splash screen. This animation that I want is in the main screen along other widgets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKKgYpC-EPQ) for flutter animated widget. It's a good start.

I think that `[AnimatedPositioned][2]` could work.